# How to Autofill data in Windows Security pop up

Tags: c#

**Overview of project**

I am working on an Automation project where I need to launch a webpage and fill out certain details.

**Progress so far**

1. I could able to launch IE and navigate to the required webpage.

**Problem**

1. As soon as I navigate to webpage we get a  windows security popup which asks the user to fill out user credentials.
2. I am struggling to get hold of the popup and pass on user credentials to proceed further.

**Screenshot**

[image]

> I couldn't get much help from google any help will be much
>   appreciated.

Comment: If the Group Policy is setup properly you would not get the POP UP.  Talk to you MIS people about setting up the Group Properly to avoid the pop-up.

Comment: check out UIPath RPA.. great tool for this type of stuff.

Comment: Keep in mind that to solve this issue you'll need to keep user credentials stored in the compiled source or in configuration.  Neither of these is considered a good practice. That said... you'll going to need to navigate to the correct window controls (See the GetWindow and EnuChildWindows functions in the Win32 API, set the focus to the correct window, and then use the SendKeys function.